# How do I run PulseAudio in a headless server installation?

Tags: 10.04, server, pulseaudio, headless

PulseAudio is the standard audio server in desktop installations. However in a server installation audio services and thus PulseAudio are not provided.

How do I install and make use of PulseAudio in a headless server?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### [Install ALSA](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Quick_Install)

```
$ sudo apt-get install libasound2 libasound2-plugins alsa-utils alsa-oss
```

#### Install PulseAudio:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils
```

#### Set Group Memberships for PA:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG pulse,pulse-access <username>
```

#### Run the PulseaudioServer:

```
$ pulseaudio -D
```

Following command tells us if a sink is recognized by PulseAudio:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
```

*Remember sinkname for output below.*

This command will **play a sound file** to a given sink:

```
$ pacmd play-file <filename> <sinkname>
```

We may need to unmute audio devices:

- for ALSA: use `alsamixer`
- for Pulseaudio: use `pacmd set-sink-mute n 0` where n is the sink index (likely 0)

For further CLI commands see also the [Pulse Audio Wiki](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/CLI)

To **configure Pulseaudio Server** to our needs we may need to edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` that come with self-explanatory. notes.

For testing the soundsystem see also[Sound Troubleshooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting)

Comment: Thanks! It works great! But in server installations the pulsaudio didn't started automatically. I also tried add "/usr/bin/pulseaudio -D" to /etc/rc.local, but it not helped. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Pulseaudio is designed to run in userspace after login. To run it as a service you need to run [pulseaudio system-wide](https://askubuntu.com/a/939338/3940)

Comment: are you running in root? could you try pulseaudio --system?

Comment: Can you be more specific