# Why was pulseaudio installed on Ubuntu server 14 after dist-upgrade?

Tags: server, apt, pulseaudio

I noticed after doing apt-get dist-upgrade that pulseaudio was using 100% of one of the CPUs on my server. I can stop it but it restarts after after rebooting. Why would this have been installed and what would be the safest way to get rid of it? I was going to use apt-get autoremove pulseaudio but then it said it was going to install other packages:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-settings-daemon  
libgnome-control-center1 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libtelepathy-glib0

Suggested packages: libcanberra-gtk-module metacity x-window-manager
The following packages will be REMOVED:
indicator-sound libcanberra-pulse pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11  
unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon    
The following NEW packages will be installed:
gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-settings-daemon libgnome-control-center1 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libtelepathy-glib0
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 6 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Don't remove it, it's part of the system.

Pulseaudio is installed by default, something else must of gone wrong here but to answer your question.

To stop pulse restarting run

```
echo "autospawn = no" > $HOME/.config/pulse/client.conf
```

This makes a file client.conf in .config/pulse that disables its autospawn, now you can kill it if you want

```
pkill -f pulseaudio
```

The system should fall back on ALSA, post a comment if no audio

Pulse should restart on boot but if it does not and you need it back then remove the file you made

```
rm $HOME/.config/pulse/client.conf
```

To stop it restarting at boot

```
cp $HOME/.config/pulse/client.conf .config/autostart
```

Comment: This thread seems to be implying that pulseaudio is not installed by default on Ubuntu Server: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28176/how-do-i-run-pulseaudio-in-a-headless-server-installation)

Comment: Yes it does but I can't seem to get a straight answer from Google on weather or not it is pre-installed as server does not seem to have its own package list, however you did use the dist-upgrade command and this will not just update installed packages but install any new packages required to satisfy any missing dependencies this could be an issue, I would try this answer for now as it should still work and is 100% reversible, then  perhaps someone else will come by and confirm if it is pre-installed or not and we can go from there.

Comment: I followed your advice and it worked great. Pulse isn't starting at boot now. Thanks.