# How can I stream my soundcard output?

Tags: sound, vlc

I want to stream the output of my sound card to my iPod, via http server. The goal is to use my hifi as loud speakers for my computer, using my iPod, wireless.
(NB. I want to stream everything to my hifi (games, music...), so streaming files is NOT a solution)

I tried a lot of things with vlc, but none of them were successful.
I tried a few inputs for vlc, but I couldn't figure out how to refer to my soundcard

- alsa://
- alsa://hw:0,0
- alsa://pulse (works, BUT it's the microphone, and not the soundcard)
- v4l2:// --v4l-adev="/dev/dsp" (my computer does NOT have /dev/dsp)
- v4l2:// --v4l-adev="/dev/snd"
- --alsadev
- --alsadev="hw:0,0"
- --v4l2-standard
- alsa:// --alsadev="hw:0,0"

Thanks

Comment: I think pulseaudio has an option to allow streaming, but I'm not 100% sure of how to set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulseaudio will let you change the recording source for an active application so that it uses "what you hear".

Run PulseAudio Volume Control, go to the recording tab, next to the name of the running application you want to change the audio source for choose "Monitor of "your card"".

And you'll want to be using pulse as your sound source in the application you're streaming from.

Here's a screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkOpw.jpg

To install run:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

It should also be in the Applications menu under Sound and Video.

To 'set as fallback' in Input Devices make sure "Show:", in the bottom, is set to "Monitors".

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You found the solution for accessing the soundcard :) I also had to change the "Set as callback" switch in "Input devices"

Answer (score 0):

We are unable to test this with an iPod wireless, but from requirements you mentioned a well established method to stream audio in a local network could be to setup an [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) server on the host machine to stream audio using an internet radio protocol.

In combination with [Ices2](http://www.icecast.org/ices.php) (for .ogg) or [Darkice](http://code.google.com/p/darkice/) (for .mp3) we are able to stream the output from the host soundcard. On the client side streams appear as if they were an internet radio station. Of course the client needs to be capable of playing internet radio stations.

A short description on how to do this for Icecast2/Ices2 can be found in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network).

To reduce choppy playback or delay: Streaming solutions may need some fine-tuning to acchieve the smallest buffer size for non-choppy playback at a given sample rate. This also depends a lot on the bandwidth of you network. Start with a lower sample rate an/or reduce buffer size and play with `flush-samples` until you get the best results for your individual hardware setup.

Comment: Works very well with @Spacecraft tip