# Stream sound card output to icecast2 via darkice

Tags: sound, streaming, devices, icecast

I want to stream to icecast server via darkice, the default .cfg comes with `/dev/dsp`, witch is OSS, but there is no `/dev/dsp` in Ubuntu 12.10, so I tried `hw:0,0`, but it's just the microphone, and I would like to stream all of the sound-card output.

Any ideas?

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xf8700000 irq 16

cat /proc/asound/devices
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  3: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  4: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
  5: [ 0]   : control
 33:        : timer
```

I tried following this post: [How can I stream my soundcard output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33349/how-can-i-stream-my-soundcard-output)

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `witch` to `which` so that online language translation services can work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the darkice configuration file (see example in `/usr/share/doc/darkice/examples`) we define the sound device in the following section:

```
[input]
device          = <device>
```

For ALSA we may give the sound card and the subdevice with the ALSA syntax `hw:1,0` for card `1`, subdevice `0`. See your card specifications with:

```
aplay -l
```

Usually however you will have defined a default device. It is therefore worth to try with the following entries:

```
device = default
device = pulse # in case we have pulseaudio running.
```

See also:

- [How do I setup an Icecast server for broadcasting audio in my network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network)

Comment: yep, "default" just work, but i have to move some config with pavucontrol

Comment: @Takkat Hi, Is the way to route icecast stream to dummy alsa device? Please advice: https://superuser.com/questions/1239805/route-icecast-stream-to-alsa-dummy-device

Answer (score 3):

Set device = /dev/dsp
Then start darkice using:
padsp darkice

padsp starts the specified program and redirects its access to OSS com‐
       patible audio devices (/dev/dsp and auxiliary devices) to a  PulseAudio
       sound server.