# How to access windows speaker from ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound

Is it possible to play a sound file which is in my ubuntu system but to the windows speaker? I am runnning ubuntu 10.04 with IP i.e 172.29.32.10 and the speaker is connected to Windows XP Professional with IP say 172.29.32.15. What i want to acheive it i just want to play a sound file in  ubuntu using the windows speaker. It means the sound should be heard in windows speaker. Possible?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. However the windows computer will have to *initiate* the playback.

What you want to do is set up your linux box as a streaming server. There are multiple packages that accomplish this, [Gnump3D](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnump3d/) is the GNU - free and open source software that will accomplish this.

There are various GUI wrappers that help you configure and use gnump3D, in essence though anything that gnump3d plays will be streamed from your computer. Any computer on the local network will be able to play audio files stored on the ubuntu computer.

**EDIT**

As Takkat pointed out (and I wasn't aware so +1 to him), Gnump3D is not in the repos for recent Ubuntu releases. You can go at it yourself (and if you do please make a post on the ubuntu forums and link in a comment here), or try other equivalent packages (Icecast, mentioned in Takkat's answer works well).

Comment: [Gnump3d is for 8.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/gnump3d) only. Gnu/Savannah server is down atm.

Comment: @Takkat thanks for that info, Haven't had to do this in a while, I knew there was an alternate just couldn't remember the name - Icecast

Comment: it was nice to hear of Gnump3d - hope someone adopts it.

Answer (score 3):

By running an [Icecast streaming server](https://askubuntu.com/q/28496/3940) you are able to stream the audio output from Ubuntu to any client capable of playing internet radio streams.