# Is there any open source software to make a Online Streaming radio?

Tags: software-recommendation, internet-radio

i'm traying to make an online radio in my home.

I've been reading and found that i need a streaming software.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.10.

Any software you know?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: see also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) is a well-known streaming media server that can do what you need. You're not too specific if you want to make a single radio station stream or just be able to have a network media player, in that case check out [Ampache](http://ampache.org/).

Comment: Thanks Jorge. My english is not very good. I'm from Argentina. I'm trying to set a simple radio station to broadcast from time to time. Does Icecast do it?

Comment: Yep, icecast is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "Setting Up Your Own Station: A Free Radio Under Linux HowTo" on http://www.osguides.net/multimedia/78-setting-up-your-own-station-a-free-radio-under-linux-howto.html