# How to achieve media streaming from my local machine to the internet?

Tags: 11.04, video, streaming

How to make Ubuntu 11.04 "desktop version" a Streaming audio/video box; Catering at least 1k users at the same time. Are there any software to achieve it.

I did use VLC player for streaming with LAN environment.

How can I do streaming the same from my local machine to the Internet?

Comment: For audio broadcasting [Icecast2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network/28498#28498) is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can even search for a p2p-tv application which runs on linux. Remember to broadcast 1000 users at normal rates which are 400kbps poorly, there is no home connection that can deal with it...
Web applications like ustream are available also.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough bandwidth to stream video to 1000 users? Perhaps services like ustream.tv and blip.tv will suit your needs.