# How do I use my PC as a Public Address system

Tags: 11.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have a set of external speakers for my pc which work very well. I have a microphone which works very well with my pc. How do I get the sound that I make into the microphone to come out the speakers and thus use my pc as a public address system for when I am giving talks in places that there is no PA system?

Answer (score 2):

By running an [**Icecast**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network/28498#28498) server we are able to stream audio to either a local network or to the internet (see also [project home page](http://www.icecast.org/)).

When running [**Darkice**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network/28498#28498) we can also stream any audio output of our local sound card live as an mp3 stream (with a minimum of 1s delay). The receiver side is OS independent but needs to be able to connect to an internet radio stream created by Icecast. Most audio players are capable to do so.