# Stream and Control Music from Ubuntu to Android

Tags: sound, android, rhythmbox, music, streaming

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 12.10, and an Android 2.3.4 (Samsung Galaxy Fit). I connect my Android to a speaker far away from me.

I want to stream music from my laptop using Rhythmbox to my phone.

I also want to change the tracks from my laptop. It should stop playing the current track on my phone and switch to the track I changed to.

How can I do that?

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

There are three options that come to my mind you have for doing so:

1. Install and run an [Icecast2 radio server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network) streaming your soundcard as radio stream to your (local) network. Connect your Android device with an Internet Radio app (e.g. [XiiaLive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.DroidLiveLite&hl=en)) that can receive a custom IP (which then is your radio stream).
2. Set up a [DLNA server on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187086/how-do-i-set-up-live-audio-streams-to-a-dlna-compliant-device) which serves the laptop's soundcard (it does not work for me, but people say they succeeded). Run a DLNA client app on the Android device (e.g. [Bubble UPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp)).
3. Don't use Rhythmbox but [vlc](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc) [image: Install vlc] music player on both ends which claim to be able to connect via a network stream.

Option 1. is tested to work with my setup (but the free version of XiiaLive caused quite some delay from over-buffering, there may be better apps around).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I installed Icecast2 and configured and started it. I also installed Darkice and configured it, but I guess it gives an error when I start it. The problem is, XiiaLive doesn't connect to the system. It show's "Connection Failed". I put the port and network host correctly, also the username and password. But it's not working! :(

Answer (score 1):

you can use Bluetooth ( & pulseaudio ):

- to stream music from the phone to Ubuntu
- to use your pc mic to do calls

Here a complete guide for ubuntu ( it is a bit tricky since there is not a gui )

http://blog.stevenocchipinti.com/2012/10/bluetooth-audio-streaming-from-phone-to.html/