# Can rhythmbox play media on my DLNA TV?

Tags: rhythmbox, dlna, rygel

I have rygel configured as DLNA server and it autostarts with my session --> Cool

On my TV I can browse/play the music, but the interface with the remote is horrible. --> Not cool

So the question is, can I let rhythmbox find my music hosted by rygel [it can, I found that], but more important, can it somehow tell my TV to play that music file?

Edit: So the end goal is to be listen to my music playing on the TV while working, and use my media keys/rhythmbox UI to change songs, without turning my head and get cranky while pushing the remote buttons.

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187086/how-do-i-set-up-live-audio-streams-to-a-dlna-compliant-device?rq=1

Comment: @Takkat, that is a neat piece of hacking, and I got that working, but it gives a horrible (but expected) delay (20sec) on the sound. Not really what I was looking for. I am looking more for something like a DLNA controller.

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?

[I have the same kind of question][1]

Thanks

  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/383549/using-ubuntu-desktop-as-upnp-dmc-digital-media-controler

Comment: No I haven't. Still searching for a solution every now and then though. Worst thing is that windows has it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna). It was designed for your purpose.

You can choose which application to play on your tv via **pavucontrol**.

[image: pulseaudio-dlna in action]