# Using Ubuntu desktop as Upnp DMC (Digital Media Controler)

Tags: 13.10, rhythmbox, upnp, dlna, rygel

I've just tested Rygel, but as I understand, Rygel is a server.

What I am looking for, is to choose the music on my computer (using Rhythmbox for example) and the file (or the stream ?) is send via upnp to a network player (Pioneer N-50 from my side).
Then the "sound" is played by the network player (connected to a hi-fi system).

This scheme is working fine with my android phone without any configuration. I can even chose the output of my phone player, or local, or network player.

I d like to be able to do the same from my Ubuntu desktop because the screen, the mousse... it's so comfortable.
Use desktop as DMC, network player as DMR.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've found the answer here [streaming audio from ubuntu to a dlna player](http://chemicaloliver.net/linux/streaming-audio-from-ubuntu-linux-to-a-dlna-player-blu-ray-or-ps3/)
and for french readers, the complete adaptation is here [UPnP DMR Pioneer](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=15715151#p15715151).

Thanks a lot.
Nick

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a UPNP DMC.
Unfortunately, they're a bit thin on the ground - have a play around with gupnp-av-cp (from gupnp-tools), which should get you started at least.