# Streaming music to Marantz M-CR603

Tags: networking, pulseaudio, streaming, mediaserver, dlna

Our [stereo installation](http://us.marantz.com/us/products/pages/ProductDetails.aspx?CatId=hificomponents&ProductId=MCR603) supports, according to the box, streaming over AirPlay (although the normal RAOP stuff doesn't seem to work on it. I think it's something called *Airport Express*), DLNA and Windows Media Sharing.

On Ubuntu, it seems almost impossible to get this thing to work, while on Windows it's possible with iTunes and [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/).

### What I've tried, and what went wrong

- Airplay: Streaming over PulseAudio

  - Music players refuse to play. Status changes to playing, but the search bar thingy and the position counter don't progress. No sound comes out of either the stereo installation or the computer. I've also tried to manually create a "Sink" (?) using `pactl load-module module-raop-sink server=192.168.1.32`. The result was the same.
- Airplay: [Stream2IP](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip)

  - I'm guessing this uses the same backend as the Pulseaudio thing, or perhaps even does exactly the same. It says it's connected, but exactly the same happens as did with the previous method. The stereo installation doesn't even recognise any kind of connection. It just continues playing what it's already playing.
- DLNA: [Stream2IP](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip)

  - When I go to *Media Server* on the stereo installation, it sees *RobinJ: Root*. *Music*, *Browse Files*, ... all go on to a screen saying *<Empty>*.
- DLNA: Serviio

  - This actually seems to work fine. The free version is limited, and it's not open source, but at least it allows me basic streaming features. However, what I'd prefer is for audio from a specific applicattion, or if possible the whole system, to get streamed to the stereo installation. Rather than me having to browse through menu's on the stereo to choose a song.
- Windows Media Sharing: Nothing

  - I have no idea how to do this on Ubuntu.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Don't just close this as an *"Exact duplicate"*, because if I haven't found an answer after looking for half a year, I think it's safe to assume that the answer is not yet on this website.

---

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, but I don't mind switching to 12.04 or 12.10, or even en different distro, if it'll work there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my observation the main reason why it seems complicated to achieve media streaming to any external hardware media devices is that the manufacturers of these devices lean back and rely on the presence of OS X or Windows on their customer's machines.

#### DLNA media file access

From the many solutions that do exist I had success with the following solutions for DLNA media access for my Internet Radio, Android Devices, and Smart TV:

- [Serviio](http://www.serviio.org/): closed source, rather sluggish on my machine.
- [Rygel](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rygel) [image: Install rygel]: default GNOME DLNA streaming server, crashes on access from some devices.
- [MiniDLNA](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/minidlna) [image: Install minidlna]: very lightweight and stable, needs to be set up from a configuration file.
- [uPnP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/upnp) [image: Install upnp]: not further developed, does not stream to all of my devices.

My favourite on that list definitely is **minidlna**, which now runs here 7/24 for several months with no issues. By default minidlna will run on startup as a service. To run it in user space you may use [stream2ip](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip) from version > 1.0, or the [MiniDLNA Application Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/175891/3940) I made for this. You will still have to set up minidlna by its configuration file first.

#### Live streams

Sadly none of these solutions are able to [stream the output of my soundcard live](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187086/how-do-i-set-up-live-audio-streams-to-a-dlna-compliant-device) to the receiver. Newer devices do not support the old RAOP protocol used by pulseaudio but seem to need the newer [RAOP2 protocol](https://github.com/zx2c4/pulseaudio-raop2) which is not (yet?) available for Ubuntu.

Live streams to external (non-Ubuntu) devices is possible in case they support the RTP protocol pulseaudio is able to stream with, but I have not found one which does.

Another possibility is setting up an [Iceast Internet Radio Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network) to generate our own private radio *"station"* in our local network. This works great but a prererequisite is that the tuner is able to connect to a stream defined by its IP-adress, and port. It should be an easy thing to do, but sadly most devices do not offer this. Instead they support Internet Radio directory services (e.g. [vTuner](http://www.vtuner.com/), or [tunein](http://tunein.com/)) which may dependent on the device not support custom radio streams to be added. From me only my radio device which operates through [Reciva](https://www.reciva.com/) has no issues playing custom streams generated from Icecast (both via [stream2ip](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip), or from command line).

---

#### Marantz

Last time I contacted Marantz (August 2012) they gave me the following information regarding support for a custom radio station:

> *"It is not possible to enter a custom radio station to your favorites. You can only select a station from the list provided by vTuner. From there you will have a choice of more than 17.000 stations."* <sup>Translated from German</sup>

We may try if adding a custom URL in a personalized instance of a radio station service  (see this [blog for Denon](http://blog.joshdzielak.com/blog/2012/11/23/stream-audio-to-your-home-theater-without-using-airplay/)) will work by now. For Marantz we can access the vTuner service on http://radiomarantz.com/. To personalize the service we need to register with the device's unique access code (likely to be the MAC). We then may be able to add the local URL of our Icecast radio stream (`<IP>:<Port>/stream.mp3`) as a custom radio station. Unfortunately due to lack of hardware we can't test this here.

Comment: Is there a way to stream whatever is playing on the system over Icecast, though?

Comment: It would be possible (and it is to another Ubuntu, Windows or Reciva driven box) but Marantz seem not to support this (see edit). They may in the meantime - do ask them!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I'm going to leave this question open for a few more days, in case a better answer comes along (which I doubt is going to happen).

Comment: Yeah, do leave it open for some while - I'd be very interested myself in case somebody had any good approach.

Comment: Doesn't look like I'm going to get a better answer that this :-)

Comment: Added some additioal information worth to try out. I found a blog post describing how to do that for Denon who use vTuner as well.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna).

It was designed to stream the sound of your applications to DLNA devices in your network.
You can choose which application to play on your device via **pavucontrol**.

[image: pulseaudio-dlna in action]

Comment: Have just tried this solution on ubuntu 17.10. It just work perfectly. This way you can stream to any DLNA enabled device.  This should be the accepted answer because it does exactly what the user asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Takkat's hint for Marantz ("...To personalize the service we need to register with the device's unique...") helped me set this up successfully with the M-CR603 and I hope my update is useful though this thread (and  the M-CR603) are quite old. The  access code  on radiomarantz.com is the device MAC. Via the Software Center I set up darkice and icecast2 on my Thinkpad W520 running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, using one of the many guides available in the public domain. On radiomarantz.com I added the local URL of the resulting Icecast radio stream (http://192.168.xx.yy:8000/stream.mp3) as a custom radio station. It worked with almost no glitches.