# Stream music from ubuntu to XBMC

Tags: 14.04, mediaserver

Hi guys I want to stream music from Ubuntu to OpenELEC.
I want something  that looks like this picture on Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Comment: There really are many options for this - one being Rygel that you apparently already have running. The perhaps easiest way for me was running [pulseaudio-dlna](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187086/how-do-i-set-up-live-audio-streams-to-a-dlna-compliant-device), a rather nice DLNA server which sets up any renderer as a sound output device. It works great with Kodi as a renderer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need either:

1. DLNA-compatible content server on Ubuntu
2. SMB (Samba) share on your Ubuntu system that your XMBC client can use.

I think [this link](http://blog.4digits.net/building-a-media-center-with-raspberry-pie-and-openelec/) would be prefect for your needs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice tutorial on how to activate network sound devices on Ubuntu, using PuleseAudio.

https://westmarch.j5int.com/2014/04/streaming-audio-linux-to-raspbmc/

on 14.04 i just had to do :

```
sudo apt-get install paprefs pulseaudio-module-raop
```

and for gst-launch to work :

```
sudo apt-get install rygel-gst-launch wavpack
```

Then activated airplay on Kodi & in pulseAudio preferences panel.

BR