# Stream audio from PC to bluetooth headset via android phone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, android

I have 16.04 Ubuntu on my Laptop (no bluetooth device on the laptop). I have a bluetooth headset and an android phone. Is there anyway I can connect my phone to the laptop and use the phone's bluetooth to redirect the audio stream from PC to the headset?

Answer (score 1):

#### On the android phone:

- install and run [Bubble UPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=en) (tested) or any other DLNA or Chromecast client
- pair and select your Bluetooth headset as output

#### On Ubuntu:

- install and run [pulseaudio-dlna](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187086/how-do-i-set-up-live-audio-streams-to-a-dlna-compliant-device) ([in the Universe repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pulseaudio-dlna) from 16.10)
- select Bubble UPnP from Sound Settings menu

[image]

Note that there will be some unavoidable lag from network buffering.