# stream audio from ubuntu to network receiver

Tags: sound, stream

Ive got a Pioneer PDX-z9 network receiver, it accepts mp3 and flac which are my audio files - i would like to play audio on that receiver from my (x)ubuntu  16.04 notebook over the local dhcp router network.

EDIT:

the dlna streaming server as suggested hast a breaking connection within seconds, see debug log. https://pastebin.com/reXmjdfd

Comment: Have a look if [pulseaudio-dlna](https://askubuntu.com/a/567075/3940) recognises your receiver.

Comment: dont have the mentioned package availablke- i edited the question for the ubuntu version info which is 16.04 (xubuntu)

Comment: yeah, only newer releases have it in the repos. For 16.04 you have to add the ppa (see in above answer). The ppa should be safe - it is maintained by the developer and contains the same packages we have in the repos. It is a pretty awesome program.

Comment: installed the git repo, ill try that one now

Comment: the program is working but ive no idea about the settings yet

Comment: Nothing to do if it works. It is designed to guess it all correctly.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/owasalicom.xml

no sound yet

Comment: Is that all output? It should say that it discovered your receiver and is ready to go. Some receivers may need some tweaks such as the `--fake-http-content-length` option but usually, if the DLNA-implementation is standard it should just work without any options given. You can test this with BubbleUPnP on an Android phone if you have one.

Comment: Oh - and of course the receiver must be ready in the network, and an application should play music.

Comment: yes, i get that. Ive also istnalled vlc and it shows the streamer device as output, if i pick it i still dont et sound even thus device appears in pavu then.

Comment: got the first sound but the connection seems to break within seconds