# How can I stream my audio output with VLC to my Android device?

Tags: sound, android, vlc

I want to use my Android device like a wireless headset, I want to stream my audio output with VLC and listen to that with an Android app. How can I make this happen with VLC? and what app can I use on my Android device to listen to it?

Note that I want to stream the audio, not just music files.

Comment: Perhaps move to Android.se?

Answer (score 1):

Like several other questions, you're essentially asking "*How do I stream audio from my computer to my Android phone?*"

The answer I would suggest is the one I've given in several other places: [use IceCast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network). That solution takes all audio and pumps it out over the network. Then you can use any-old-Internet-radio client to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried streaming live cricket match to other systems in my dorm using VLC, but that was around 3 years back, you can refer this link for how it is done.

http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html

Comment: it's dead by now

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp). It's cross-platform and has an Android app as well as a web interface. That way, you can control the music from the phone, and not have to run back to the server to change songs or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use the [Google Music](http://music.google.com/) or the [WinAmp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp&hl=en) app.
I use both of them for the same purpose as yours and I have had no problems.