# What low latency live streaming solutions exist for low bandwidth connections

Tags: 12.04, streaming

In a couple of weeks in my country there will be a open source event (FLISOL) and the group is trying to figure out how to stream the event live with a slow connection.

What options are in Ubuntu that can help in streaming the live event with a low speed device over the internet.

The internet speeds vary between 8KB/s up to 40KB/s and we want a way to have low latency without sacrificing a lot of quality.

Since the event will be on the 28th and 12.04 will come out on the 26th. the version of Ubuntu that will be used will be 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest and most stable solution would be to set up an [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) server where you can define the bandwith per mount point (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network)). This will also allow very low bitrates at the cost of quality of course.

By using [Darkice](http://darkice.org/) as a streaming client you are able to stream the sound output of your soundcard, which would alos allow mixing of microphone or other sources before streaming. To set up Darkice for low bandwith streams you may edit the [configuration file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/darkice.cfg.5.html) included e.g. like follows:

```
[icecast2-0]
bitrateMode     = cbr       # fixed bit rate
quality         = 1.0
format          = mp3       # format of the stream: ogg vorbis
bitrate         = 32        # bitrate of the stream sent to the server
[...]
```

Both applications are available through the repositories: [icecast2](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/icecast2) [image: Install icecast2] and [darkice](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/darkice) [image: Install darkice].