# Ubuntu for Internet radio

Tags: streaming, internet-radio

I am planning to set up a streaming server purely for internet radio using Icecast2.
what software packages do i require during Ubuntu installation and any third party apps i may require.

I am going to use BUTT(Broadcast using this tool) Encoder and would like to be able to run BUTT on any computer so that other people can broadcast to my server from anywhere.

I am looking for tips or tutorials on how to achieve the above.
I mainly need info on cofiguring Ubuntu Server and icecast2.

Also GUI? if so what one. Preferablly lightweight.
I am choosing Ubuntu for its level of security and reliability.

I hope someone can help me as i plan to make this a community Radio station.
Many Thanks

Khz

Comment: See if there is enough information for a start here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network. If not don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: do you want to learn how to configure icecast2 or you want to learn how to setup Ubuntu server ? or both ? am confused :)

Answer (score 1):

apt-get install icecast2

Afterwards we must edit /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml. Most default values should work fine for now, but you should change the passwords in the ... section. The source-password is the password that Ices2 will later on use to connect to Icecast2; the admin-password is the password that the admin will use in Icecast2's web interface; we won't use the relay-password, but anyway you should change it.

vi /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml

```
[...]
    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>password1</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>password2</relay-password>

        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>password3</admin-password>
    </authentication>
[...]
```

Afterwards edit /etc/default/icecast2 and set ENABLE to true:

vi /etc/default/icecast2

```
# Defaults for icecast2 initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/icecast2
# installed at /etc/default/icecast2 by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# Full path to the server configuration file
CONFIGFILE="/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml"

# Name or ID of the user and group the daemon should run under
USERID=icecast2
GROUPID=icecast

# Edit /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml and change at least the passwords.
# Change this to true when done to enable the init.d script
ENABLE=true
```

That's it already, we can now start the Icecast2 server:
/etc/init.d/icecast2 start

You can now direct your browser to http://:8000/ (replace 192.168.0.100 with your own IP address or FQDN) and browse through the web interface.

There is a couple more settings to change depending on your intended use. But that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with it but there's Airtime by sourcefabric [here](http://www.sourcefabric.org/en/airtime/download/).

Looks awesome and pretty easy, there's also a pro version.