# Setting up Icecast2 streaming server on the Internet for live streaming

Tags: streaming, icecast, ices

I have looking through tutorials for setting up Icecast2 server and ices2 on Ubuntu. Unfortunately all of these are based on LAN. I want to set up a Icecast server on a ubuntu machine which will be connected 24/7 to the Internet. The clients need to access the streams, the server provides from across the globe. Assuming the server has a static IP, how do i configure Icecast? Also I have a Behringer UCA 202 as a capture source. How do i configure ices2 to use this as a live capture source and stream it to the the above mentioned server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After we followed

- [How do I setup an Icecast server for broadcasting audio in my network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network)

we will be able to create an Icecast2 radio stream from the default pulseaudio output device in our system.

In case we have setup the input source (e.g. here your Behringer UCA 202) to output to this default sink (i.e. we are able to listen to the input on our local machine) this will then be sent as an Icecast stream to our network.

If we want to reach this Icecast server from the Internet we can do so via the following radio URL:

```
http://<ip_of_server>:<port>/<name_of_stream>
```

Replace `<ip_of_server>` with the external IP of the network where the Icecast server runs. Replace `<port>` with the port Icecast uses for streaming (defaults to 8000 as defined in `/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml`). Also give the name of your mount point as defined in the `ices-alsa.xml` or `darkice.cfg` file you are using (e.g. `stream.ogg`).

> **We need to open and forward the listen port for access to the Icecast server from the Internet.**

Listener authentification can be defined in the `icecast.xml` file as well as we can define another relay server for our stream if needed for bandwith or accessibility.

Further information on settings can be found here: [Icecast2 Documentation](http://www.icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.3.3/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [darkice](http://packages.ubuntu.com/darkice) for streaming from input devices instead of ices2. See this thread:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/28498/94697

[ices2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ices2) is used for vorbis-streaming, e.g. ogg-playlists.

[ices0](http://www.icecast.org/ices.php) is used for lame-streaming, e.g. mp3-playlists.