# Ubuntu how can I send my audio output, to the mobile which is connected using bluetooth?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, sound, android, bluetooth

My mobile running Android which is using bluetooth connected to my Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

[image]

My goal is to have following step:

- In my Ubuntu desktop I am running music from YouTube
- Mobile phone is connected to Ubuntu Desktop using bluetooth
- From my mobile I have a head phone connected to my ear
- I want to hear the music from my mobile the same audio which is playing in desktop

How can I do that? in this popup dialog I don't have any kind of option to send audio output on bluetooth.

Follow up:

[image]

Comment: [Soundwire](http://georgielabs.cjb.net/) which doesn't work with Bluetooth but with WiFi does exactly what you want, but as I said it's WiFi not Bluetooth.

Comment: Thank you, using wifi it works. But packet gets broken and audio is not stable, also i have two kind of sound output, only one kind of sound output works. But the thing works nicely.

Comment: I think you are connected(audio streaming) using Internet (not Wifi)

Comment: You could look into this tutorial and change the sound input into sound output
http://blog.stevenocchipinti.com/2012/10/bluetooth-audio-streaming-from-phone-to.html/

Answer (score 2):

If you use Blueman instead of gnome bluetooth manager you can set uo your phone as sound output.

You can find Blueman in Software Center

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to do this in the past, searched for answers and the basic answer for this question is that you **can't do it**, because the android bluetooth stack **lacks support for A2DP sink** capabilities.

Then I found a great answer at stackoverflow which says that it might be possible to do it, but it's hard to do. The answer and the details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15559902/3061119). For the solution presented in that answer you will need:

- a rooted device.
- Good programming skills/experience. *(Or someone who does it for you)*
- Android version older than 4.2, because in 4.2 Android switched from the BlueZ stack to Broadcom's Bluedroid.

But I don't know whether the solution presented in that answer really works, because I never tried it. Maybe in the future Google will change the default bluetooth stack to support the A2DP sink profile or some modders make a custom ROM with support for it, but until that day this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that using Wifi is okay, so here's an easy solution to your problem. [Set up Icecast](https://askubuntu.com/a/28498/1736) on you machine and set the audio source to something like stereo-mix (see the chapter on Darkice).

On your mobile device just install any player capable of playing streams (e.g. VLC for Android or Tunein Radio, both free and both available for Android and iOS) and point them to your stream.

If you desperately want to use Bluetooth there should be a way. You [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892506/use-android-device-as-a-headset-for-another-device) simply use the Android device as a Bluetooth speaker. But you could create a virtual pulseaudio recording device that just records everything played (i.e. monitor soundcard) and use this as a bluetooth microphone. Now you need an app on your mobile device that plays out loud what is recorded on the microphone (like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.bitplane.android.microphone&hl=en)). For the pluseaudio part you could ask for details on the [IRC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat) channel [#pulseaudio](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=pulseaudio) on freenode.net.

Comment: More detailed answer to come. I'm just testing this with my iphone. It's easier than I though, you just need to pair your device and loud a pulseaudio loopback module with your device as a sink. With pavucontrol you can then set the sink to monitor your soundcard.

Comment: Bluetooth doesn't work anymore for me since upgrading Ubuntu, so I can't test this, but here's how it should work. Run `pactl list short sinks` after pairing to get the sink NUMBER of your device. Then run `pactl load-module module-loopback sink=NUMBER` to add a loopback to that sink. In `pavucontrol` in the recording tab you can now set that loopback to *monitor soundcard*.

Answer (score 0):

You could also save the Android output and connect your bluetooth headset to your ubuntu machine, just set it up as any other device but in "Device Type" just select headphone (or something like that)