# I want to send audio via bluetooth to an android phone - kubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, android, bluetooth

There are a number of items that I found during the search, like:
[Ubuntu how can I send my audio output, to the mobile which is connected using bluetooth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260880/ubuntu-how-can-i-send-my-audio-output-to-the-mobile-which-is-connected-using-bl)

There is an answer with +100, stating that Android lacks the A2DP capabilty. As far as I can make out, in the meantime there is an applet by the name of [SoundAbout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix&hl=en) that is supposed to do just that. 
I installed it, paired the devices.

And what I get is like the image in 
https://cjenkins.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/use-a-wireless-bluetooth-speaker-on-ubuntu-12-04/
, except it says A2DP source (Receive Audio)

I have installed `blueman`, and I get quite a lot, but no other output device ever pops up in `pavucontrol`. Therefore, everything is and remains quiet. `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` is installed.

How can I get to make the sound system see the device?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have tried doing this a few times and its a world of pain , i gave up and used DLNA over the wifi to abstract audio playback and accepted the lack of live audio as a limitation. Wifi is a far better medium for sending audio, bluetooth can be very buggy and there are a lot of broken implementations of bluetooth audio out there. I've never found one that doesn't occasionally freak out for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what SoundAbout is - its not an A2DP profile for your android bluetooth stack - its an audio router that allows you to configure how audio generated in the android device is routed, very similar to what pulseaudio does (possibly it uses pulseaudio?).

What you want is not possible with stock android, because the Bluetooth stack on Android does not support the A2DP *sink* profile. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104611/how-to-modify-androids-bluetooth-stack-to-enable-a2dp-sink) for further explenation on that and how to create an application that enables bluetooth A2DP sink.

You might get ahead more by replacing the default Android bluetooth stack with the bluez stack used on modern Linux distribution, though it does require replacing the kernel which you can only do if you have a rooted or customized device. [see here for details](https://01.org/bluez-android).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered setting up a DLNA server instead?

Currently, I use MiniDLNA to run a media server that can stream music to devices that can use DLNA. There are apps for Android that provide DLNA clients, like UPnPlay.

MiniDLNA is now called ReadyMedia, but the software is still called minidlna(d). It's very easy to set up through a config file.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA

Comment: By the way, Bluetooth has a very limited physical range. If you want a broader range, use DLNA on a wireless network. If you don't have a wireless network, then perhaps Bluetooth is worth looking at.

Comment: Agreed, & bluetooth does not have the bandwidth to deliver audio at music quality, most Bluetooh headphones do horrible compression to achieve a half decent frequency range. IMHO. Wifi is the way to go for phones.

Comment: It is totally possible to do audiophile grade audio via bluetooth with some of the more advanced proprietary codecs but this dramatically limits the bluetooth devices you can use and rules out linux.  I do agree that Wifi is far more capable

Answer (score -1):

Have you made your device's Bluetooth visible. In your Android Phone go to

**Settings** *-->* **Bluetooth** *-->* **Make Visible**

If you have already did this, try to *reboot your computer and your phone* and *try again*.

Comment: I don't understand: the OP has clearly stated he has `blueman`.  So it is unlikely you will help him by suggesting using it.