# Multiple pulseaudio multicast "channels"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm running a ubuntu server, I've configured it with a pulseaudio RTP multicast sink. This sink is in use for a multitude of applications.

What i'm looking for now is if there is a way to have an additional "channel" for RTP multicasts, so the same computer can multicast different streams at the same time, and if i can then configure my computer to just accept one of those channels.

It could be compared to different zones in a home audio sound system, where every zone would have it's own multicast "channel"

Is this possible, and in that case how would it be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to send more than one concurrent RTP stream via your local network by assigning a different Multicast IP to each of them with:

```
# stream 1
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp1 format=s16be channels=1 rate=44100 sink_properties="device.description='rtp1'"
pactl load-module module module-rtp-send source=rtp1.monitor loop=0 destination=224.0.0.56
# stream 2
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp2 format=s16be channels=1 rate=44100 sink_properties="device.description='rtp2'"
pactl load-module module module-rtp-send source=rtp2.monitor loop=0 destination=224.0.0.57
```

and then listen on the receiver to the corresponding IP with

```
pactl load-module module-rtp-recv sap_address=224.0.0.56 # resp. 224.0.0.57
```

However I was unable to test if this really works how I think it should.

In addition, this method has several disadvantages:

- for each RTP sending stream we need to define it's own (exclusive) sink.
- sending multiple **uncompressed** audio streams via our network will inevitably lead to congestion, as these streams will take a lot of bandwith.
- we need a script solution to be able to select a *"channel"* from the streams on the receiver side.
- generating multiple simultaneous RTP streams will need quite some CPU power on the server, so this is possibly risky.

---

A much better alternative that I would like to suggest here is to set up an [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) Server on your Ubuntu server. It is no so hard to do:

- [How do I setup an Icecast server for broadcasting audio in my network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network)

With this solution you will be able to

- stream **compressed** audio data (e.g. ogg or mp3) in your network
- send multiple audio channels (i.e. *"radio stations"*) simultaneously
- switch easily between these streams from the receiver (which could then also be an Internet Radio receiver, or a smartphone) just from the name of the stream
- Ices2 resp. Ices help you to stream playlists, Darkice to stream data of your sound card.

Comment: Icecast would sound like a good solution, but does icecast support client synchronization to ensure simultaneous playback? From what i know it doesn't

Comment: @DelusionalLogic: not that I know, I doubt you can do that with Icecast. Can you sync RTP?

Comment: From what I've read it would seem like pulseaudio supports syncing the different receivers of the multicast, assuming they all have a fairly tightly synced time.