# Unable to install darkice in ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: 12.04, installation, icecast

I'm trying to install darkice with "apt-get" by looking at [this tutorial here](http://www.geeklk.com/2012/07/broadcast-audio-online-with-icecast-darkice-and-ezstream/).. but it says unable to locate the package. And I've downloaded a .tar from their web.. extracted the package, cd into it & when I try to use `./configure`, it runs and stops with some errors. I've actually mentioned it in [their support page](http://code.google.com/p/darkice/issues/detail?id=96) but no one seems to reply to it yet.

Please advise me or just simply show me a guide to install icecast, ezstream and darkice to an ubuntu distro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install [Darkice](http://packages.ubuntu.com/darkice) [image: Install darkice] from the Ubuntu **multiverse** repositories we have to enable this repository in our sources settings (disabled by default).

Here is our basic tutorial on how to setup Icecast and Darkice:

- [How do I setup an Icecast server for broadcasting audio in my network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network)

Comment: I also have another problem when compiling darkice now.. It give the same exact same error as seen on this [link] (http://icecast.imux.net/viewtopic.php?t=7007&sid=1edf9aa8b71fc6dcd69b0950b12df66e)

Comment: Dont know if that is what you mean: the audio `[input]` device to scan is defined in the settings .cfg file. Other than in various guides mentioned it should be `device=pulse`, or `device=default` on a system running pulseaudio.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm referring to.. and below is what I get when compiling..

`Using config file: livestream/darkice.cfg
Using ALSA DSP input device: pulse
Using POSIX real-time scheduling, priority 98
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM pulse
DarkIce: DarkIce.cpp:1187: can't open connector [0]`