# Icecast2 streams microphone input instead of sound card output

Tags: pulseaudio, streaming, icecast

I'm trying to set up my laptop (14.04 32 bit) to broadcast the music it is playing (using Clementine) to my local wireless network. That way I can listen to my music everywhere on this network using my phone (using an internet radio streaming app).

So far;
[This excellent tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network) has helped me set up icecast2 and darkice in such a way that I can hear the stream from my phone, however, the broadcasted stream is what is registered by my laptop's microphone! So I'm hearing myself type, all the noises in the room etcetera.

This probably means I didn't select the proper device somewhere.
The above tutorial mentions (under the darkice heading) that

> *To enable streaming of the local soundcard we may need to define the recording device for Darkice in pulseaudio first. This can be done with pavucontrol. Install pavucontrol. In the Recording tab choose Monitor of  for the "ALSA plug-in [darkice]".*

So pavucontrol is installed, but the Recording tab shows

> *No application is currently recording audio.*
>
> *Show: all streams*

Hmm...

To see my sound devices, I used the command **aplay -l** which produced;

> List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices
>
> card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: CX20561 Analog [CX20561 Analog]
>
> Subdevices: 0/1
>
> Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>
> card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: CX20561 Digital [CX20561 Digital]
>
> Subdevices: 1/1
>
> Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Then I fiddled with darkice configuration.
Currently it is working somewhat with the following in my darkice.cfg;
    [input]
    device = hw:0,0
...But this results in my laptop's built-in microphone to be used as the source of the stream.

Thanks for reading about my issue. Hope you can help!

Comment: Thanks for helping @Takkat! In my pavucontrol configuration tab, it was set to **Analog Stereo Duplex** so I changed that to **Analog Stereo Output**. Also I used 'device=default', restarted the icecast and darkice processes, and NOW IT WORKS ! Yay ! And the pavucontrol recording tab now shows the ALSA plug-in [darkice] as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on our settings it may be that while streaming to Icecast Darkice will also pick up the audio from our microphone.

To overcome this we may make the following settings:

1. Turn on default audio device in `darkice.cfg` to ensure streaming from the default device:

   ```
   [input]
   device          = default
   ```
2. Disable duplex audio profile in [pavucontrol [image: Install pavucontrol]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol):

   [image]

   alternatively either mute audio input, or select a non-attached input (e.g. line)

   [image]