# Numlock doesn't work after logging in

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, numlock

I've a strange problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10

The Numlock of my Apple Keyboard (white, wired) doesn't work anymore. Strange thing because it works with the guest account but not with my user account. I did change the lightdm.conf to get the numlock working for the login and it works, but nor in my user account.

Even stranger, pushing zero effects a right click?

I also tried different keyboard layouts, but it shows Numlock on (stuck on) but doesn't work.

Any idea which config file stores information about this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41747/how-do-i-fix-f10-f11-and-f12
Maybe something in here could help you.

Comment: Is number lock stuck on, or stuck off? That is, what happens when you press the keys on the numeric keypad?

Comment: he say's it works when he's not logged in...

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with my Dell and could solve it:

**Universal Access** -> **Pointing and Clicking** -> **Mouse Keys** -> **Off**

Comment: +1 This answer has tremendous usefulness to cumbersomeness ratio.

Comment: @Vorac: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Could you please explain?

Comment: Just being happy that you helped me a lot, while not wasting my time (short answer, right to the point). :)