# How to broadcast audio output to iPhone?

Tags: sound, iphone, client

Is it at all possible to broadcast the usual audio output to an iPhone or similar device? So sort of audio server (Desktop) to client (iPhone).

**more details**: Ubuntu 10.04/11.04 or 11.10, iPhone 3S or 4. It is my understanding that the sound system shipped in Ubuntu can be used as a sound server. The idea would be for the sound system to stream to a remote audio client, for example sitting in a different computer or an iPhone, that computer/iPhone could be connected to a audio amplifier in a different location than the computer where sound/music is played from. The streaming is of course by means of a local (wireless) network. (Although via bluetooth can be a solution also)

Comment: Could you explain more what you want? What model do you have? what os are you useing,etc etc. You need to give us more information

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers

Answer (score 1):

By running an [Icecast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network/28498#28498) server we are able to stream our local sound to any device that is capable of tuning in to an Icecast/Shoutcast internet radio stream. I don't know if an iPhone already comes with this functionality but there likely may be an app to make this possible.

If you prefer a graphical frontend rather than a command line solution to start the streaming service you may try out [stream2ip](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip).

Comment: ok, I set up the icecast server following the directions from the link, can anyone recommend a client app? the ones I tried (Liveshout, Radio Lite) cannot connect to the client server (a password issue?)

Comment: @alfC: You may need to open the port (default 8000) to your Icecast server in the router/firewall settings.

Comment: I am using it in a home network, so I unless Ubuntu blocks that port, I don't think that is the problem (?)