# How do I directing sound to a remote PulseAudio server?

Tags: 11.10, networking, sound, pulseaudio

I've configured PulseAudio server on a PC that is connected to stereo system. I've had no problems directing audio from my notebook running Ubuntu 10.10 to it - remote audio device just appeared in output device list in sound preferences. No such luck with Ubuntu 11.10 on my wife's netbook though. I've managed to enable Network Access in paprefs after symlinking /usr/lib/pulse-1.0 to /usr/lib/pulse-1.0.0, but there are no remote sound devices in sound preferences, padevchooser is removed in this release and pavucontrol doesn't see any remote devices either. Can this be fixed or is pulseaudio network features are indeed considered 'unneeded' in newer Ubuntu releases?

Additional details: PULSE_SERVER environment variable does work, but that's not convenient enough in this case to say the least; avahi-browse does see the PulseAudio server, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stream music over the network to multiple computers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers)

Answer (score 1):

I found a replacement for padevchooser here:
https://launchpad.net/~christoph-gysin/+archive/pasystray

I haven't tried it yet, but it's supposed to make directing audio over the network possible again.