# Multiple simultanous streaming with pulseaudio

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stream music over the network to multiple computers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers)

On a home network with three pcs now powered with Ubuntu 12.04, I would like to send audio from one pc to the other two using pulse audio. In effect I want the same music playing simultaneously throughout my house. This would remove any need for apple airports, and remove Windows from one of the dual boot Dells.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stream music over the network to multiple computers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers) also think of setting up an [Icecast Server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network) in case bandwith matters.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Answer made to this questions here:

[How do I setup an Icecast server for broadcasting audio in my network?](https://askubuntu.com/a/28498/41387)

Make sure you install `pavucontrol`(PulseAudio Volume Control) as mentioned in order to redirect Computer Sound Output to the server. There will be a delay between Computer Output and Output on Receiving Devices but that's sadly unavoidable.