# Pipe a single application's sound to another machine via pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, banshee

Is there any way to output a single (or multiple, but only select) application sound to another machine using the pulseaudio multicasting (or something similar)?

My exact setup is the following:

main machine hooked up to headphones running banshee, wine (running WoW), and mangler (linux native vent voip client)

second machine with speakers running ubuntu server (with a full unity desktop installed and banshee)

Currently I run synergy between both and control the banshee on the server and utilize it as a jukebox but I find it annoying to have to rsync my songs and play counts/ratings/banshee.db every so often. I would like to be able to just run banshee on my main machine and pipe the output to the server. Ive tried several media servers etc and havent been too happy with them (mainly the controls/interface are to blame).

So... help me obi-wan-community! You're my only hope :)

Answer (score 1):

follow this link: [How to stream music over the network to multiple computers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers) to set it up. one change i had to do was to use pavucontrol to pipe only the banshee sound like was suggested in the pictures. the unity volumecontrol didnt seem to have the option.