# how to play video on one ubuntu and audio on another synchronously in the same WLAN

Tags: wireless, sound, video

I want to watch video on one Ubuntu machine, and hear the sound on another.

I tried PulseAudio as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers), but the delay was too long.

Is there a solution that will let me watch the video, while the audio played synchronously on another machine?

Comment: just out of curiosity: why would you want to do that? Moreover, you might wabnt to share how the two machines are connected to eachother....

Comment: @Bruni they are both on the same WLAN.
I have one machine connected displaying on TV, and headphones that I want to use but their cable can only reach a laptop on my table.

Comment: I guess you can't speed up the transfer and lower the audio delay, so you will have to set up a video delay in your player application instead. E.g. in `vlc`: Menu "Tools" -> "track synchronization"