# Play sound on all PCs in a network

Tags: networking, sound

We have 15 PCs in our network. If there is a big meeting, we want to play a sound (from a file, just some seconds) on all PCs in our network.

Most of them run Ubuntu, some run SuSE.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the source if this sound?

Comment: @mbiber the source is a file on disc on a server.

Comment: Is it important for them to start at the exact same moment? What is the purpose for this - why play the file on all PCs?

Comment: @mbiber a delay of up to 5 seconds is ok. Why play the file: to inform people.

Comment: Can you SSH into all those PCs? Do they all have access to the network location where the file is stored? Use `play` command to play the file. So something like `ssh user@hostname play /location/of/file.mp3` on each of the PCs. If up to 5 seconds delay is ok then you can simply use for loop to run that command. Something like `for PC in list of hostnames; do ssh user@$PC "play /location/of/file.mp3" &; done`

Comment: @mbiber yes, ssh to the hosts could work. Please write this as answer, and I will up-vote it. Thank you.

Comment: @mbiber Don't forget that `ssh` with password authentication will stop and wait till you enter the password. You need to set key authentication if you wish this script to run seamlessly.

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough. It is very case specific but almost you haven't provided detail about it.

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha what details are you missing? What do you want to know?

Comment: You want to stream a sound or play an audio file?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha I want to play a simple file from the file system. Just some seconds long. I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `play` command to play the file. So something like `ssh user@hostname play /location/of/file.mp3` on each of the PCs. If up to 5 seconds delay is alright then you can simply use a for loop to run that command from any PC. Something like `for PC in list of hostnames; do ssh user@$PC "play /location/of/file.mp3" & done`.

Setting up public key authentication will eliminate the need for password inputting for each of the hosts. [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/46930/158442)

Comment: You may want to link to `parallel` to avoid scripting. "a shell tool for executing jobs in parallel using one or more computers": https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 0):

I think streaming audio in your network can be a solution for your case.

have a look on this question: [How to stream music over the network to multiple computers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers)