# Bluetooth headset: using mic with a2dp?

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset, a2dp

Is it possible to use the mic and headphone simultaniously when using a2dp? the sound quality is really bad when using hsp/hfp.

Comment: There won't be a microphone in a2dp profile by design.

Comment: ah yes true, it's a duplicate. Is there a wireless technology that gives me hd playback and recording?

Comment: Pulseaudio can do this. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers and https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#index3h3

Comment: I tried to use the solution provided by Takkat, but I did not get it working. What is the trick to use the mic and HD audio at the same time when connected via BT?