# How to do a "silent movie", share audio from browser with multiple headphones?

Tags: server, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, streaming

I would like to show an outdoor movie for a group of 10 people in my apartment's courtyard, but I can't allow open-air sound. Therefore, I wanted to set-up a "silent movie" (similar to a "silent disco") where each movie-goer can hear the movie's score in their headphones.

To pull this off, I followed the suggestions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers).

I set up an audio streaming server using pulseaudio, and I could stream my computer's audio over the LAN to multiple connected devices.

However, with a few different attempts to configure this set-up, I had noticeable problems. Either the audio in the connected devices was very poor quality, or it had noticeable latency issues. Therefore, I turned to a different set-up using [darkice](http://www.darkice.org/), but this too suffered from the same issues.

Getting audio from my browser to multiple headphones is turning out to be more difficult than I thought. Has anyone done something similar to what I'm trying to do with the two methods I mentioned above? Did it work for you?

If not, does anyone have a suggestion how I might do a "silent movie"?

Specifically, I want to realize the following configuration:

1. connect my computer to my projector via hdmi
2. project my computer's screen on my wall
3. stream a movie to my computer's browser
4. share the audio from my browser with between 8-10 smartphones connected to headphones in my LAN.

Obviously, I require that the browser audio be in sync with its picture, and the audio quality in the headphones be as high as possible.

Comment: You're never going to realistically find a way to simultaneously stream audio to a random assortment device that you don't own and can't install software to.  My suggestion is to obtain and use a FM transmitter to "stream" an audio track so people can listen in with a radio.  Then all you have to do is project the video.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a purely hardware-based solution :)
Plug the audio output from your computer into a FM transmitter (they can be bought from audio outlets for a cheap price).
Tell the people to use the FM radio in their phones and tune to the frequency on which your FM transmitter operates.

The simpler the better :)